# Radio buttons in for loop only allows one selection for all iterations

Tags: html, django, for-loop, radio-button

I am working on building an attendance submission form (pictured below) in Django, but I am not currently using the Django Forms. I am having an issue with the radio buttons allowing only one selection for all iterations of the for loop.

In the HTML, it loops through a list of students and within each of those iterations, it loops through a list of attendance types. Each attendance type is represented by a radio button because only one attendance type should be able to be chosen. However, this only allows one option to be selected for the whole for loop, instead of allowing one option to be chosen for each student.

```html
{% for student in list_of_students %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{student}}</td>
        <td>
            {% for attendanceType in list_of_attendanceTypes %}
                <input type="radio" name="attendancetype" id={{attendanceType}} value={{attendanceType.attendancetypeid}}>
                <label for={{attendanceType}}> {{attendanceType}}</label><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to do this without changing the name of the buttons in each iteration of the for loop?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can only select one option over all radio button is because all radio buttons has the same name "attendancetype", try having different radio button group names, ex. "attendancetype_studentA" for each students :)

```html
{% for student in list_of_students %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{student}}</td>
        <td>
            {% for attendanceType in list_of_attendanceTypes %}
                <input type="radio" name='{{student}}_attendance' id={{attendanceType}} value={{attendanceType.attendancetypeid}}>
                <label for={{attendanceType}}> {{attendanceType}}</label><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm now trying to format the radio-buttons to look like buttons. I tried the typical solutions, but then it only allows me to select an option for the first student in the list. I'm assuming it has to do with where I put the <div>, but I tried it in a few different places, and none of them worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more details or snippets of how it looks now and what your desired outcome is?

Comment: I created a new question so that I could give more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76765475/format-radio-button-like-button-in-for-loop